# Changing a kbd tag element background color, after a key is pressed, then reverting back to original color

Tags: javascript, dom, settimeout

I am trying to change a KBD tag color when a key is pressed then reverting back to the original color, but my code does not seem to show effect on the brower.

Here is the code:

```css
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.code=="KeyA") {
    let audio1=new Audio("piano_A.mp3");
    audio1.play();
    highlight("A");
  }
  else if (event.code=="KeyS") {
    let audio2=new Audio("piano_B.mp3");
    audio2.play();
    highlight("S")
  }
  else if(event.code=="KeyD") {
    let audio3=new Audio("piano_C_sharp.mp3");
    audio3.play() highlight("D")
  }
  else if(event.code=="KeyF") {
    let audio4=new Audio("piano_D.mp3");
    audio4.play()
  }
  else if(event.code=="KeyG") {
    let audio5=new Audio("piano_E.mp3");
    audio5.play()
  }
  else if(event.code=="KeyH") {
    let audio6=new Audio("piano_F.mp3");
    audio6.play()
  }
  else if(event.code=="KeyJ") {
    let audio7=new Audio("piano_G.mp3");
    audio7.play()
  }
  else {
    console.log("Press only the following keys: A S D F G H J") let str="Press only the following keys: A S D F G H J" document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML=str.blink(); // not blinking
  }
}

);
function highlight(id) {
  let obj=document.getElementById(id);
  let orig=obj.style.backgroundColor;
  obj.style.backgroundColorcolor='#FFFF99';
  setTimeout(function() {
    obj.style.color=orig;
  }
  , 1010);
}
```

the effect is not showing up in the browser when i press the keys

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have to use proper event.code to the keys you want. Please check [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/)

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer submit, but when I try this code, it doesnt even play anymore, and it says it cannot use keycode

Comment: You can try changing `event.keyCode` with `event.which` as suggested in the article. You can also cash your audios outside of the event listener and just try to play them inside keydown event.

Answer (score 0):

Change the event code keys with their actual code number. Also, change `event.code` to `event.keyCode`.

```css
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode==65) {
    let audio1=new Audio("piano_A.mp3");
    audio1.play();
    highlight("A");
  }
  else if (event.keyCode==83) {
    let audio2=new Audio("piano_B.mp3");
    audio2.play();
    highlight("S")
  }
  else if(event.keyCode==68) {
    let audio3=new Audio("piano_C_sharp.mp3");
    audio3.play();
    highlight("D")
  }
  else if(event.keyCode==70) {
    let audio4=new Audio("piano_D.mp3");
    audio4.play();
  }
  else if(event.keyCode==71) {
    let audio5=new Audio("piano_E.mp3");
    audio5.play();
  }
  else if(event.keyCode==72) {
    let audio6=new Audio("piano_F.mp3");
    audio6.play();
  }
  else if(event.keyCode==74) {
    let audio7=new Audio("piano_G.mp3");
    audio7.play();
  }
  else {
    console.log("Press only the following keys: A S D F G H J") let str="Press only the following keys: A S D F G H J" document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML=str.blink(); // not blinking
  }
}

);
function highlight(id) {
  let obj=document.getElementById(id);
  let orig=obj.style.backgroundColor;
  obj.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFF99';
  setTimeout(function() {
    obj.style.backgroundColor = orig;
  }
  , 1010);
}
```

Comment: The audio works, yes I can also put it outside of the document listener, but how come the color of the elements do not change, I got it to work briefly, then it stopped working

Comment: This error probably comes from the highlight function. You should change the background to `orig`, not color. `obj.style.backgroundColor = orig;` Also, there is an error in setting the new color, it should be `obj.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFF99'.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote
> I just realized where the issue is.... in front of my face the whole time....

obj.style.backgroundColorcolor = '#FFFF99';

I did this.... not sure why when I posted the code, it is correct though